# How to Instantiate prefab when have a collision c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to instantiate a prefab in unity when I have a collision.

Here is my code:

```
if (IgnourColl.Ddeer = true) {

    Instantiate(Deer, new Vector3(TPlayer.transform.position.x + 5, TPlayer.transform.position.y, 0), Quaternion.identity);
    IgnourColl.Ddeer = false;
}
```

`IgnourColl.Ddeer = false;` is a bool, which becomes true if there is a collision.

I add false after true so that instantiate stops until another collision ...

Everything works fine, but the if statement doesn't work, and instantiate is not stopping after the first prefab instantiates.

Comment: Can you post the whole function?

Comment: `if (IgnourColl.Ddeer = true)` is also incorrect and should throw a compiler warning asking if you really meant to do *assignment* and not *comparison.*  There's also no need for `== true` anyway. `if(IgnourColl.Ddeer)` is sufficient.

Comment: Also also, are you working in *C#* or *UnityScript*? You've tagged your question with both even though the description for UnityScript *explicitly says* "do not use this tag for scripts which are in C#"

Comment: now seems to be good , but now i make the speed of deer 0 when he enter collision with player .... how i make it back to 9 to deer witch instantiate and the deer he collide still 0 ?!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i replace the instantiate by make a box collider that he make the deer game object appear when he collide with player so i don't need  instantiate

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me , but using "OnCollisionEnter()"  will do things on collision enter.
No need to set it to false.

Comment: okay thxx a lot .. 
now i make the speed of deer 0 when he  enter collision  .... how i make it back to 9 and the deer he collide still 0 ?!!

Comment: I think i didn't understand your question , there is the "OnCollisionExit" to do things when collision ..is over

Comment: the speed of deer 0 when if he enter collision with player .... how i make it back to 9 to deer witch i will instantiate and the deer he already  collide still 0 ?!!

Comment: That is a separate question to the one you asked. If you have a different question, ask it in a new question...

Comment: I still can't understand what he means.

Comment: i have more than one Deer and i want to stop the Deer that he collide with player ... how to do that ?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do, I would make an IEnumatator and make it wait. I suggest you as @ḞḹáḿíṅḡⱫỏḿƀíé said, to post another question